# Toggle button using CSS

Tags: html, css

I designed a horizontal toggle button and I am trying to make it vertical with vertical transition.

You can look for my CSS demo at [Horizontal Toggle button CSS Code Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZX6hF/5/) Can someone point me what needs to be done to make it vertical? I am new to CSS and HTML

```
Refer to my code at jsfiddle
```

Comment: hi I have posted the answer below check the given links

Answer (score 6, accepted):

replace your css with the follwing ..

http://jsfiddle.net/ZX6hF/8/

or

http://jsfiddle.net/ZX6hF/9/

```
html{ height:100%; }
body{
  font:14px/1 Arial; 
  text-align:center;
  color:#333; 
  background-color:#EEE; 
  height:100%; 
  background:#DDD; 
}
body::after{ content:''; display:inline-block; height:100%; vertical-align:middle; }

*{ margin:0; padding:0; }

            ul{ margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; display:inline-block; width:300px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; }
                ul li{ line-height:30px; overflow:hidden; padding:4px 0; }

/* Actual code goes here */
      .togglebox input{ display:none; }
            .togglebox{ display:inline-block; border:1px solid #BBB; width:40px; height:90px; position:relative; border-radius:20px; color:#FFF; font-weight:bold; overflow:hidden; box-shadow:0 1px 0 #CCC; }
            .togglebox label{ width:40px; height:100%; line-height:200%; border-radius:0.4em; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; z-index:1; font-size:1.1em; cursor:pointer; -webkit-transition:height 0.12s; -moz-transition:height 0.12s; transition:height 0.12s; }
            .togglebox span{ position:absolute; top:-110px; }

            .togglebox label::before{ content:'ON'; width:40px; height:50px; float:left; margin-top:00px; padding-top:20px; padding-right:13px; text-align:center; background:#13E27F; text-shadow:0 -1px 0px #093B5C; box-shadow:0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset; }

            .togglebox label b{ display:block; height:40px; width:40px; float:left; position:relative; z-index:1; border:1px solid #AAA; background:#F6F6F6; box-shadow:0 4px 0 -2px #F1F1F1 inset, 0 2em 2em -2em #AAA inset, 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5); border-radius:20px; margin-top:-20px; margin-left:-1px; }
            .togglebox label:hover b{ background:#E5E5E5; }
                .togglebox label::after{ content:'OFF'; width:40px; float:left;height:50px; padding-top:20px; padding-left:0px; text-align:center; background:#E70A25; box-shadow:0 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3) inset; margin-top:-20px;}
            .togglebox input:checked ~ label{ top:-50px; }
```

check the sample Here ..!!! [click](http://jsfiddle.net/ZX6hF/8/)

Comment: isn`t it upside down?

Comment: if you want upside down check this one [http://jsfiddle.net/ZX6hF/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZX6hF/9/)

Comment: It's not upside down if you live in the UK :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
#togglebox {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY IT**  https://jsfiddle.net/DEVANGHIRE/0a9mnrfv/1/

```
 .toggleSwitchForPublishZone {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    padding: 0;
    /*margin-left: 50px;*/
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 40px
}

.toggleSwitchForPublishZone * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .toggleSwitchForPublishZone label,
 .toggleSwitchForPublishZone>span {
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .toggleSwitchForPublishZone input:focus~a,
  .toggleSwitchForPublishZone input:focus+label {
      outline: none;
  }

.toggleSwitchForPublishZone label {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
 }

 .toggleSwitchForPublishZone input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 5;
  }

 .toggleSwitchForPublishZone>span {
    position: absolute;
    left: -50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .toggleSwitchForPublishZone>span span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    width: 100%;
    left: 15%;
    top: -1px;
    opacity: 0;
  }

 .toggleSwitchForPublishZone a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    z-index: 4;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    left: 2px;
    width: 18px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  }

  .toggleSwitchForPublishZone>span span:first-of-type {
    color: #ccc;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 56%;
  }

.toggleSwitchForPublishZone>span:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 51px;
    top: -2px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  }

 .toggleSwitchForPublishZone input:checked~a {
    border-color: #fff;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -8px;
  }

  .toggleSwitchForPublishZone input:checked~span:before {
     border-color: #00A08B;
     box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 30px #00A08B;
    }

   .toggleSwitchForPublishZone input:checked~span span:first-of-type {
        opacity: 0;
   }

   .toggleSwitchForPublishZone input:checked~span span:last-of-type {
       opacity: 1;
      color: #fff;
    }


  .toggleSwitchForPublishZone.large1 {
       width: 60px;
       height: 25px;
   }

   .toggleSwitchForPublishZone.large1 a {
      width: 27px;
      top:1%;
   }

  .toggleSwitchForPublishZone.large1>span {
    height: 29px;
    line-height: 28px;
    }

  .toggleSwitchForPublishZone.large1 input:checked~a {
    left: 41px;
    top:1%;
   }

   .toggleSwitchForPublishZone.large1>span span {
     font-size: 11px;
   }


    <label class="toggleSwitchForPublishZone large1">&nbsp;
    <input type="checkbox" name="FlgInstanceRelease" id="ChangeStatus1" checked 
    data-status="1" />
    <span>
            <span>No</span>
            <span>Yes</span>
    </span>
    <a></a>
  </label>
```